# IE11 "This page can't be displayed"

Tags: internet-explorer

I'm having trouble accessing a site which authenticates via SSL certificate. IE11 installed itself today, now that page says "This page can't be displayed". All add-ons, etc have been disabled.

Comment: Is the site is up? Can you ping the site to confirm that it is up? Can you access the site using other browser?

Comment: It seems I can login, but it works intermittently. Can't quite tell if it's our end or theirs. It's a reasonably big site.

Comment: Check with others in your area to see if they are having the same issue. And also check if you are having access/internet issue in general (happening to any site). If you can confirm that your internet is fully up and no issues, then it could be the website end. Also is it only happening with IE11, or other browser as well?

Comment: The site seems to be ok. It is happening to two machines at different locations at present. I've downgraded one to IE10 and still seeing intermittent issues.

Comment: If you downgrade and still seeing intermittent issue, internet connectivity (or site issue) could be the cause rather than browser specific.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the the internet option of ie11, and go to Advanced, and uncheck the SPDY/3. That should resolve the problem.

Comment: I cannot find SPDY/3 in advanced option. Under HTTP setting I've only Use HTTP 1.1 and Use HTTP 1.1 through proxy connections but not Use SPDY/3. I am on Win7/IE 11

Answer (score 0):

I had a conflicting program, namely WideCap (a proxifier), which caused IE to not work properly. After uninstalling it and a reboot, everything worked fine again.